# Map Domain Alias to Virtual Folder in IIS6

Tags: asp.net, iis, mod-rewrite

How could I go about mapping a domain alias, e.g. `domainAlias.co.za`, to a virtual folder under, e.g. `mainDomain.co.za`, so that all requests to `domainAlias.co.za` actually get served by `mainDomain.co.za/domainAlias` ?

Comment: What version of IIS?  Maybe add "in IISx" to the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used it, but IIS has a [URL Rewrite Module](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-url-rewrite-module/) that can [import Apache mod_rewrite rules](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/470/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules/).  There is also a document that compares [IIS URL Rewriting and ASP.NET routing](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/496/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing/).  With some research, you should be able to get that working.

Comment: @Kevin:  Thanks, I'll check those out.

Comment: The URL Rewrite Module works for IIS7, not on earlier versions of IIS.

Answer (score 1):

A URL Rewriter like [IIRF](http://iirf.codeplex.com) lets you do this.

The rules would be:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^(?!mainDomain)([^\.]+)\.co\.za$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$       /%1/$1   [L]
```

In English, this rule says:  if the host is NOT maindomain.co.za, but still ends in .co.za, then rewrite the URL so that it is prepended with /domainAlias/.  With this rule, you get:

```
input                         output
-----                         ------
http://foo.co.za/a.php        http://main.co.za/foo/a.php
http://foo.co.za/a.aspx?r=1   http://main.co.za/foo/a.aspx?r=1
```

You can also go one level further and make the rewrite conditional on the presence of the directory, something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^(?!mainDomain)([^\.]+)\.co\.za$
RewriteCond c:\wwwroot\%1  -d
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$        /%1/$1   [L]
```

This says: if the host is not maindomain.co.za, AND the directory c:\wwwroot\domainAlias exists, then rewrite to prepend ....

But in that case you might instead want to do the converse - test for lack of existence of the directory - and redirect to a 404:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^(?!mainDomain)([^\.]+)\.co\.za$
RewriteCond c:\wwwroot\%1  !-d
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$        -   [NF]
```

NF = 404

you can also do [F] which is a 503 (Forbidden).

IIRF works on IIS5, IIS6, or IIS7.

Answer (score 0):

You can use routing.

```
System.Web.Routing
```